# Placement issue with nested Div tags

Tags: css, html, css-position, html-table

I have the following Div hierarchy:

```
<div id="DivTop">
    <div id="DivTopLeft" style="float: left; width: 45%; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        Top left content.
    </div>
    <div id="DivTopRight" style="float: right; width: 45%; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        Top right content.
    </div>
</div>
<div id="DivBottom" style="float: none;">
    <div id="DivBottomFinePrint" style="float: none; font-size: 8px; text-align: right;">
        Fine print content. This content appears between the `DivTopLeft` and `DivTopRight` divs.
    </div>
    <div id="DivBottomGridView">
        <asp:GridView ...>
    <div>
</div>
```

The content of `DivBottomFinePrint` appears between the `DivTopLeft` and `DivTopRight` divs. Also, `DivTop` and `DivBottom` seem to have the same Y coordinate whereas I want `DivBottom` to start vertically after `DivTop` finishes. I can specify the top margin for `DivBottom` but that requires hard-coding a value which I do not want to do.

Is there a way around this without using tables?

Comment: did you try adding `DivTop` a style of `clear:both;` for your float?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña: That was it! Although the tag needs to go on `DivBottom`. I was using `float: none;` instead. Thank you.

Comment: then ill put it into an answer so that this question has an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this style in your container:

```
#DivTop{
  clear:both;
}
```

float the elements, left or to the right, which creates an empty space on the other side which allows other elements to take up the remaining space.